# Find All Records Based on Two Conditions: Time and IP

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

What I am trying to do is to find all records that have the same object_id that occurred within a second of each other but have different client_ip addresses.

Below are a few examples that I have found manually but I would like to be able to identify all records in the table for a particular date.

```
SELECT sa.client_ip, sa.action_occured, sa.[object_id]
--INTO #TmpB
FROM dbo.system_audit AS [sa]
WHERE sa.action_id = 9111 AND sa.object_type_id = 9100
AND sa.[object_id] IN (50017197, 50050471, 50100927,50145858,50144558);
```

And the results:

[image: IP and Action Occurred]

Sample data might help more than a screen shot:

```
client_ip                     action_occured           object_id
fe80::7996:b7de:c335:699b%12  2016-12-19 15:54:17.300  50017197
fe80::e41f:6383:5d0d:7b3%3    2016-12-19 15:54:17.410  50017197
fe80::e41f:6383:5d0d:7b3%3    2016-12-19 14:54:45.383  50050471
fe80::2117:63d8:2b67:91ab%12  2016-12-19 14:54:46.303  50050471
fe80::7996:b7de:c335:699b%12  2016-12-19 15:40:42.467  50100927
fe80::e41f:6383:5d0d:7b3%3    2016-12-19 15:40:42.763  50100927
fe80::7996:b7de:c335:699b%12  2016-12-19 14:12:54.147  50144558
fe80::118c:f37b:336d:c1c0%12  2016-12-19 14:12:54.270  50144558
fe80::b0de:8ce7:be87:582d%12  2016-12-19 14:20:30.770  50145858
fe80::149b:f256:e64c:4d59%12  2016-12-19 14:20:31.380  50145858
```

Without knowing the specific object_id, is there a way I could compare the records to find all object_id's that did occur within a second of each record but have different client_ip's?

Thanks,

Comment: You could LAG/LEAD this one. Order your result set by action_occurred and then have your query look at the following row for if the datediff is under 1000ms. Would try to write the query out but there is no sample data provided with an easy way to reproduce it.

Comment: Thanks @dfundako - I will check out LAG/LEAD but I also added some sample data if you would like to reproduce it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [dfundako](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5464747/dfundako), here's a way you could do it with `LAG`/`LEAD` (and a CTE for clarity):

```
WITH augmentedData (client_ip, action_occurred, [object_id], prev_date, prev_ip, next_date, next_ip)
AS
(
    SELECT  *, 
            LAG(action_occurred, 1)  OVER (PARTITION BY [object_id] ORDER BY action_occurred) AS prev_date,
            LAG(client_ip, 1)        OVER (PARTITION BY [object_id] ORDER BY action_occurred) AS prev_ip,
            LEAD(action_occurred, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY [object_id] ORDER BY action_occurred) AS next_date,
            LEAD(client_ip, 1)       OVER (PARTITION BY [object_id] ORDER BY action_occurred) AS next_ip
    FROM system_audit
)

SELECT  client_ip,
        action_occurred,
        [object_id]
FROM augmentedData 
WHERE (DATEDIFF(MS,prev_date,action_occurred) < 1000 AND prev_ip <> client_ip)
   OR (DATEDIFF(MS,action_occurred,next_date) < 1000 AND next_ip <> client_ip)
ORDER BY action_occurred
```

Comment: Thank you for this - very helpful.